# How Do I Update An Object in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, document

I have been facing some problem while updating the data in the db using mongoose, Therefore thanks in advance for the help.

I have been sending some data from a dynamic form that contains different set of fields each time... but when i update the array in the db it changes those fields.

This was my controller function earlier:-

```
exports.savePageContent = (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.body.dest;  // getting page data document id
    delete req.body.dest;
    var arr = [];

    // When we are returning the same page each time after we submit the data for the particuklar section form then how are we supposed to redirect the user to next page once he is done doing all 

    var fieldKeys = Object.keys(req.body);
    for(let i = 0; i < fieldKeys.length; i++)
    {
        arr.push({fieldRef : fieldKeys[i], fieldValue : req.body[fieldKeys[i]]});
    }

    pageDataModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {pageData : arr}).exec(function(err, result) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else { 
            console.log("data is inserted");
            req.flash('message', "Data Saved Successfully");
            
        }
    })

}
```

I also tried a few updates and then moved to this portion

This is my new controller function :

```
exports.savePageContent = (req, res, next) => {
    const pageid = req.body.dest;  // getting page data document id
    delete req.body.dest;

    var fieldRefData = "";
    var fieldValueData = "";

    var fieldKeys = Object.keys(req.body);
    for(let i = 0; i < fieldKeys.length; i++)
    {
        fieldRefData = fieldKeys[i];
        fieldValueData = req.body[fieldKeys[i]];

       try{

        pageDataModel.update({id : pageid, "pageData.fieldRef" : fieldRefData}, {$set : {"pageData.$.fieldValue" : fieldValueData }}, {upsert : true}).exec(function(err, result) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else { 
                console.log("data is inserted", result);
            }
        });

        req.flash('message', "Data Saved Successfully");

       }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        req.flash('message', "error Occurred updating Data ");

       }
    }

    

}
```

To elaborate the case for better understanding:-

This is the data that comes first time in the body

```
[
  { fieldRef: 'sec1.1.h1', fieldValue: 'this is the field value 1' },
  { fieldRef: 'sec1.1.p', fieldValue: 'this is the field value 1' },
  { fieldRef: 'sec1.1.a', fieldValue: 'this is the field value 1' },
  { fieldRef: 'sec1.2.h2', fieldValue: 'this is the field value 1' }
]
```

and This is the data that comes the second time :-

```
[
  { fieldRef: 'sec2.1.h1', fieldValue: 'this the field value 2' },
  { fieldRef: 'sec2.1.p', fieldValue: 'this the field value 2' },
  { fieldRef: 'sec2.1.a', fieldValue: 'this the field value 2' },
  { fieldRef: 'sec2.2.h1', fieldValue: 'this the field value 2' }
]
```

when i want both the data's in the db but when i send one the second data the first one gets updated to the second one and vice versa..

this is the db images of the scenario

[this is the data in the document on the first operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WnSE.png)

[this is the data in the document on the second operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8MQx.png)

i am not able to keep and update them both... so please help me ...

This is the error that I am getting most of the time which says that the query is wrong

```
MongoServerError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
    at /home/pushkar/Desktop/NodejsWebApp1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/update.js:80:33
    at /home/pushkar/Desktop/NodejsWebApp1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:272:25
    at handleOperationResult (/home/pushkar/Desktop/NodejsWebApp1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/server.js:370:9)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/pushkar/Desktop/NodejsWebApp1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:479:9)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at processIncomingData (/home/pushkar/Desktop/NodejsWebApp1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/pushkar/Desktop/NodejsWebApp1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22) {
  index: 0,
  code: 2
}
```

Also if I was unable to make my scenario clear please leave a comment and I will try to explain it more clearly..
thanks In Advance

Comment: The issue may be your client calling the endpoint.  Log your backend values, and post your client code.

Comment: With the set function I am getting an error that path id is not defined

Comment: see suggestion to use _id instead of id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this should solve the issue :

```
pageDataModel.updateOne({_id : "61d73f31cb5681b85618995a", "pageData.fieldRef" : "sec2.c" },{"$set" : {"pageData.$.fieldValue" : "Mkc" }}).exec(function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: great ! for other people seeing this, replace hard coded values with dynamic variables. Thanks

Comment: update is depreciated for version greater than 6.1.7 , hence we are using updateOne with better query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`$set` will replace a new value for the key. If you use the 3rd value then the `$set` will replace the 3rd value, use `$push` instead of `$set` operator.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: $set will update the element attribute for the matching index.  Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `_id` instead of `id`.

```js
pageDataModel.update({_id : pageid, "pageData.fieldRef"}) {
```

Or even `pageData._id` instead of `id`.

```js
pageDataModel.update({'pageData._id' : pageid, "pageData.fieldRef"}) {
```

Furthermore, your id is a `string` in the query, but an `object id` in database, so call a helper.

```js
pageDataModel.update({'pageData._id' : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(pageid), "pageData.fieldRef"}) {
```

Comment: please check the edited error part..

Comment: please post an example of your full document, including the id field.

Comment: ok i'll do that

Comment: apart from that the id coming to the controller is '5eb985d440bd2155e4d788e2' which also seems a problem as the find by id is not able to understand it as object id

Comment: i looked at your data source and will add another suggestion.

Comment: okay, Apart from that ill also try using findOneAndUpdate() as well

Comment: between the objectId format and the correct id field, it should work

Comment: yeah i'll be trying that in a moment, And also thanks for being there to help :-)

Comment: hi.. its not working...

Comment: what it does is that it either changes the object or else says a success message but still doesnt puts any data in the object as it cannot find that field

Comment: you need to post the db object that 'contains' pagedata array. also req.body.dest, your id, is going to interfere with your looping of keys. does your input put the keys in another property?

Comment: No, let me explain:-
I am receiving form data from the client side which is a pair of keys and values.
The key from the above data is stored in "fieldRef" and Value in "fieldValue".
Now when I am trying to update the array by checking that the "fieldRef" from the DB matches the key from form data then it shall update that particular "fieldValue" with the value else it should upsert a new object with fieldRef and fieldValues as key and value.. and I am ubanle to do it.

Comment: `const pageid = req.body.dest` body contains `dest` property. `var fieldKeys = Object.keys(req.body);` you will be using `dest` as a field key.

Comment: No, dest is the document id

Comment: `Object.keys(req.body)` is pulling it out and trying to set it as a key. you should exclude it when iterating the keys posted